# Ways to reduce memory transfer overhead in OpenGL ES 2.0 / OpenGL 2.1 with EGL 1.4 for rendering offscreen

Tags: c++, opengl-es, gpu, egl, mesa

I'm fairly early into trying to do some image manipulation tasks on a headless embedded device running linux with a MALI 400 GPU. This supports OpenGL ES 2.0 through an official driver, and possibly a mostly complete OpenGL 2.1 through an unofficial LIMA driver.

Specifically, I have images which come into a DMA mapped memory via an external system, and I load them to a (`MONO8`/`LUMINANCE`) texture, run the shader program which renders into another texture, and then read that out for use with `glReadPixels`. I can post more complete code if it would help anyone, but for now I show just the relevant parts of the setup to avoid clutter (all pretty standard I think):

```cpp
// Setup code:
display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
eglInitialize(display, &major, &minor);
const EGLint configAttributes[] = {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
  };
eglChooseConfig(display, configAttributes, &config, 1, &numConfigs)
const EGLint pbufferAttributes[] = {
        EGL_WIDTH, 1920,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 1200,
        EGL_NONE
};
surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, pbufferAttributes);
const EGLint contextAttributes[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE
};
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttributes);
eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context);

... Setup shaders, VBOs, etc ...

// Texture used to load image
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)malloc(1920 * 1200 * sizeof(unsigned char));
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 1920, 1200, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data); // Bind to dummy data at first, check if we can remove this
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// Texture used to render into
GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1920, 1200, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
```

```cpp
// LATER: In main loop
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // Start timer for image loading
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 1920, 1200, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.img); // Load current image into texture from before
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texture1"), 0);
auto text_loaded = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // Texture is loaded, end timer for image loading
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glFinish();
auto gl_finished = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // All rendering should be done when glFinish returns?
glReadPixels(0, 0, 1920, 1200, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, preprocessed_img_buf);
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // End timer for readout
// This is needed to get back into MONO8 format
for (int i = 0; i < 1920 * 1200; i++){
  processed_img_buf[i] = preprocessed_img_buf[i * 4];
}
// Print frame times
auto text_loaded_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(text_loaded - start).count();
auto frame_render_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(gl_finished - text_loaded).count();
auto frame_readout_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - gl_finished).count();
```

Attempting to get a loose benchmark with the above code, I am seeing time I can barely believe:

```
Image loading time: 7148 us
Render time: 85720 us
Readout time: 158734 us
Total frame time: 251602 us

Image loading time: 4797 us
Render time: 85841 us
Readout time: 152563 us
Total frame time: 243201 us

Image loading time: 6018 us
Render time: 85757 us
Readout time: 158420 us
Total frame time: 250195 us
```

I was going into this expecting `glReadPixels` to be slow, but not twice the render time/slower than 10 FPS (assuming I am benchmarking in a fairly sane manner). This leads me to think I am doing something else wrong, however everything I have tried seems to be unsupported in some way or another:

- Tried using the proper `GL_LUMINANCE` texture to render to, but was getting errors, it appears that my EGL does not have a configuration with only one 8bpp channel so I cannot render that way, as I understand it?
- Tried using `GL_LUMINANCE` format on `glReadPixels`, only to find that it is unsupported with that function from the docs, only `GL_RGB`, `GL_RGBA`, `GL_ALPHA` are said to be supported
- Tried hacking my shader to use just the alpha channel so I don't need to read 4x redundant data, and calling `glReadPixels` with `GL_ALPHA`, but despite the docs, I was met with invalid op error (maybe I misconfigured something else earlier for that to happen though?)
- Tried looking into other types of buffers/objects (pixmap, renderbuf, pixelbufferobj, data buffers) but all seem to have some kind of limitation which make them unsuitable for this (mostly format/use case/lack of support)
- Looked into EGL images, but am horribly confused by them and don't want to break the part of my code that seems to be working how I expect, and from what I can tell they are more for inputs anyway, so my thought process is I would rather attack the part taking more than half the time

## So my title question: Is there a way I can do this more optimally in the case I have described?

What would that combination of options/setup look like? I came into this thinking it was do-able, and now I am doubting if this GPU can be useful to me without major time investment. Is that the case or am I a few enums away from a more reasonable frame time?

And some more thoughts/questions I've had, but don't want to consider part of the main question to avoid unfocusing it:

- Although probably insanely complicated, I could probably leverage the DMA controller/memory in my system to do this transfers as fast as they would normally go out to a screen. Is that possible and would it even help, or am I overestimating the power of the MALI 400 and it was never intended to drive 1920x1200?
- I could also try to compile the LIMA drivers and get access to GL 2.1, but I am still trying to learn GLES and EGL for this, so I am wary about stacking more things to learn on unless there is promise I can achieve what I am looking to do.
- Would having the driver be open source be helpful in itsself? I have done very little in the way of driver development, and none on GPUs, so I am not exactly sure how ambitious that is, although I feel I might honestly be more comfortable doing that than trying to do what I thought would be a simple task in GLES.

Comment: Doing GPGPU stuff like read pixels on a 15 year old GPU is optimistic - drivers weren't written for those scenarios back then. Maybe could be improved with a new open source driver? Sounds like a lot of work...

Comment: @BenClark less optimistic and more constrained, unfortunately. I understand this is not the intended use case, but right now it's sitting unused in the system so I am trying to find a way to get anything useful out of it. It seems to have the power to be useful, if I can just leverage some of the other advantages I have like access to fast memory and DMA with some open source drivers, maybe that can make something of it. I appreciate your input

Comment: You could use the GBM library. First, create a GBM surface with one or more GBM BOs. Next, create an EGLSurface from it to do your rendering. If your driver supports it, you could then get a DMA fd for each BO using the DRM PRIME API. This would allow you to mmap them and read their contents as you like. P.S. You would need create the GBM surface with a linear format modifier.

Comment: @ehopperdietzel Do you know of anywhere I could look for an example of something like this? I had to step away from this project for a little bit but now that I am working on it again, this seems promising. I have gotten as far as enabling the DRM core/lima driver for it, and compiling Mesa myself so that it has GBM support. I can create a `gbm_device` from my `/dev/dri/card0`, creating a `gbm_surface` from that, and using that to create an EGLsurface/context. **I'm a bit fuzzy with how the PRIME API comes into play though, and how that would help me get a pointer to the rendered data**

Comment: @ehopperdietzel Sorry to @ you twice, I assume you mean to use `GBM_BO_USE_LINEAR`, can you explain or point me to an explanation for this choice as well? Forgive me as I have only learned of tile based rendering after looking it up now, and from what I can tell, this would just increase performance since I am not doing anything with depth, so binning/tiling is not needed? Or am I entirely off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use the GBM library for your task. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Create a GBM surface with one or more GBM BOs (Buffer Objects).
2. Proceed to create an EGLSurface from the GBM surface for rendering purposes.
3. If your graphics driver supports it, you can obtain a DMA file descriptor (fd) for each BO using the DRM PRIME API. This will allow you to mmap these buffers and read their contents as needed.
4. It's important to note that when creating the GBM surface, ensure that you use a linear format modifier so that the mapped memory's content is meaningful for your use case.

Below is an example that demonstrates rendering content into a GBM surface and saving the result into a PNG image using the mapped DMA file descriptor:

**meson.build**

```
project(
    'OpenGL DMA Read Example',
    'c',
    version : '0.1.0',
    meson_version: '>= 0.59.0',
    default_options: [
        'warning_level=2',
        'buildtype=debug'
    ]
)

c = meson.get_compiler('c')

include_paths = []

include_paths_sys = [
    '/usr/local/include',
    '/usr/include/drm',
    '/usr/include/libdrm',
    '/usr/include/freetype2'
]

foreach p : include_paths_sys
    if run_command('[', '-d', p, ']', check : false).returncode() == 0
      include_paths += [include_directories(p)]
    endif
endforeach

egl_dep             = c.find_library('EGL')
glesv2_dep          = c.find_library('GLESv2')
drm_dep             = c.find_library('drm')
gbm_dep             = c.find_library('gbm')
freeimage_dep       = c.find_library('freeimage')

executable(
    'dma-read',
    sources : ['main.c'],
    include_directories : include_paths,
    dependencies : [
        egl_dep,
        glesv2_dep,
        drm_dep,
        gbm_dep,
        freeimage_dep
    ])
```

**main.c**

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <gbm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xf86drmMode.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <FreeImage.h>
#include <linux/dma-buf.h>
#include <linux/dma-heap.h>

#define PNG_PATH "/tmp/dma_read.png"
#define DRM_DEVICE "/dev/dri/card0"
#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT 512
#define FORMAT GBM_FORMAT_ARGB8888

static int drmFd, dmaFd;
static char *map;
static int offset;
static unsigned int stride;
static struct gbm_device *gbmDevice;
static struct gbm_surface *gbmSurface;
static struct gbm_bo *gbmBO;
static EGLDisplay eglDisplay;
static EGLContext eglContext;
static EGLSurface eglSurface;
static EGLConfig eglConfig;

static const EGLint eglConfigAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
};

static int matchConfigToVisual(EGLDisplay egl_display, EGLint visual_id, EGLConfig *configs, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        EGLint id;

        if (!eglGetConfigAttrib(egl_display, configs[i], EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &id))
            continue;

        if (id == visual_id)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

static int chooseEGLConfiguration(EGLDisplay egl_display, const EGLint *attribs, EGLint visual_id, EGLConfig *config_out)
{
    EGLint count = 0;
    EGLint matched = 0;
    EGLConfig *configs;
    int config_index = -1;

    if (!eglGetConfigs(egl_display, NULL, 0, &count) || count < 1)
    {
        printf("No EGL configs to choose from.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    configs = (void**)malloc(count * sizeof *configs);

    if (!configs)
        return 0;

    if (!eglChooseConfig(egl_display, attribs, configs, count, &matched) || !matched)
    {
        printf("No EGL configs with appropriate attributes.\n");
        goto out;
    }

    if (!visual_id)
        config_index = 0;

    if (config_index == -1)
        config_index = matchConfigToVisual(egl_display, visual_id, configs, matched);

    if (config_index != -1)
        *config_out = configs[config_index];

out:
    free(configs);
    if (config_index == -1)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int getDMAFDFromBO(int drmFd, struct gbm_bo *bo)
{
    struct drm_prime_handle prime_handle;
    memset(&prime_handle, 0, sizeof(prime_handle));
    prime_handle.handle = gbm_bo_get_handle(bo).u32;
    prime_handle.flags = DRM_CLOEXEC | DRM_RDWR;
    prime_handle.fd = -1;

    if (ioctl(drmFd, DRM_IOCTL_PRIME_HANDLE_TO_FD, &prime_handle) != 0)
        goto fail;

    if (prime_handle.fd < 0)
        goto fail;

    // Set read and write permissions on the file descriptor
    if (fcntl(prime_handle.fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(prime_handle.fd, F_GETFL) | O_RDWR) == -1)
    {
        close(prime_handle.fd);
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("Got BO DMA fd using DRM_IOCTL_PRIME_HANDLE_TO_FD.\n");
    return prime_handle.fd;

fail:

    prime_handle.fd = gbm_bo_get_fd(bo);

    if (prime_handle.fd >= 0)
    {
        printf("Got BO DMA fd using gbm_bo_get_fd().\n");
        return prime_handle.fd;
    }

    printf("Failed to get fd for handle %u: %s\n", prime_handle.handle, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

int mapDMA()
{
    map = mmap(NULL, HEIGHT * stride, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dmaFd, 0);

    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        map = mmap(NULL, HEIGHT * stride, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, dmaFd, 0);

        if (map == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            void **dummy = NULL;
            map = gbm_bo_map(gbmBO, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GBM_BO_TRANSFER_READ, &stride, dummy);

            if (!map)
            {
                printf("Failed to map DMA fd.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int init()
{
    drmFd = open(DRM_DEVICE, O_RDWR);

    if (drmFd < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to open DRM device %s.\n", DRM_DEVICE);
        return 0;
    }

    gbmDevice = gbm_create_device(drmFd);

    if (!gbmDevice)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GBM device.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(gbmDevice);

    if (eglDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
    {
        printf("Failed to get EGL display.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!eglInitialize(eglDisplay, NULL, NULL))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize EGL display.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!chooseEGLConfiguration(eglDisplay, eglConfigAttribs, FORMAT, &eglConfig))
    {
        printf("Failed to choose EGL configuration.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);

    if (eglContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        printf("Failed to create EGL context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    gbmSurface = gbm_surface_create(
        gbmDevice,
        WIDTH,
        HEIGHT,
        FORMAT,
        GBM_BO_USE_RENDERING | GBM_BO_USE_LINEAR);

    if (!gbmSurface)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GBM surface.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, (EGLNativeWindowType)gbmSurface, NULL);

    if (eglSurface == EGL_NO_SURFACE)
    {
        printf("Failed to create EGL surface.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay,
                   eglSurface,
                   eglSurface,
                   eglContext);

    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);

    // Create a single BO (calling gbm_surface_lock_front_buffer() again before gbm_surface_release_buffer() would create another BO)
    gbmBO = gbm_surface_lock_front_buffer(gbmSurface);
    gbm_surface_release_buffer(gbmSurface, gbmBO);

    stride = gbm_bo_get_stride(gbmBO);
    offset = gbm_bo_get_offset(gbmBO, 0);
    dmaFd = getDMAFDFromBO(drmFd, gbmBO);

    if (dmaFd < 0)
        return 0;

    if (!mapDMA())
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

void savePNG()
{
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
    gbm_surface_lock_front_buffer(gbmSurface);

    struct dma_buf_sync sync;
    sync.flags = DMA_BUF_SYNC_START | DMA_BUF_SYNC_READ;
    ioctl(dmaFd, DMA_BUF_IOCTL_SYNC, &sync);

    FIBITMAP *image = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits((BYTE*)&map[offset],
                                                   WIDTH,
                                                   HEIGHT,
                                                   stride,
                                                   32,
                                                   0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF,
                                                   false);

    if (FreeImage_Save(FIF_PNG, image, PNG_PATH, PNG_DEFAULT))
        printf("PNG image saved: %s.\n", PNG_PATH);
    else
        printf("Failed to save PNG image: %s.\n", PNG_PATH);

    FreeImage_Unload(image);

    sync.flags = DMA_BUF_SYNC_END | DMA_BUF_SYNC_READ;
    ioctl(dmaFd, DMA_BUF_IOCTL_SYNC, &sync);

    gbm_surface_release_buffer(gbmSurface, gbmBO);
}

void render()
{
    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    // Red
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glScissor(0, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Green
    glViewport(WIDTH/2, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glScissor(WIDTH/2, 0, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glClearColor(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Blue
    glViewport(0, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glScissor(0, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Black
    glViewport(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glScissor(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

int main()
{
    if (!init())
        return 1;
    
    render();
    savePNG();
    return 0;
}
```

To test it, place the files in the same directory and run these commands:

```
$ meson setup build
$ cd build
$ meson compile
$ ./dma-read
```

If everything goes well, a PNG file like the one shown should be saved in `/tmp/dma_read.png`.

[image]

Comment: I have only one other question; Is this example something you've written from scratch or is it adapted/taken from some book or resource I could take a look at for more details? I have been really struggling with this project because there are so many different technologies at play, and I do not have enough time to go in depth and learn which ones I need/how they interact, so high level examples like this are incredibly helpful. Many many thanks either way, this demonstrates almost exactly what I was looking for and has helped me greatly in making progress.

Comment: I agree, there's very little documentation for these technologies. I borrowed most of the example code from a C library I created called [SRM](https://github.com/CuarzoSoftware/SRM), which is aimed to simplify DRM/KMS app development with OpenGL ES 2.0. It might be helpful for your use case, or you could study its source code, as that's how I primarily learned about these technologies, by examining the code from the Mesa project.